# Substract 10 years from time variable in netCDF-file

Tags: netcdf, python-xarray, datetime64

I need to substract 10 years from the time variable (dimension) in a `netCDF`-file.

The original input file starts at **1969-06-20 00:00** and ends at **1971-07-01 00:00**, with 3H time steps. The time unit in the original file is unix `seconds since 1970-01-01`, indicated as `datetime64[ns]` format in Python. I want to substract 10 years from every timestep so that the new file starts with **1959-06-20 00:00** and end at **1961-07-01 00:00**.

I am loading the netCDF-file in Python with `xarray` and substracting 10 years by using `np.timedelta64`.
Then I  convert and save the modified dataset as a new netCDF-file, see my code below.

```
import xarray as xr 
import numpy as np

# load original file
ds = xr.open_dataset('original_file.nc')
ds = ds.load()

# substract 10 years from time dimension
ds['time'] = ds.time - np.timedelta64(3652, 'D')

# save modified dataset as new nc-file
ds.to_netcdf('new_file.nc')
```

I am experiencing two problems.

Firstly, since my file contains a leap year (1960) it is not sufficient to use 365.242 days/yr * 10 yrs = 3652 day, as a result the output is one day off and starts at **1959-06-21 00:00**. But I get the following error message what I try to use`np.timedelta64` with the years `'Y'` option:

```
UFuncTypeError: Cannot cast ufunc 'subtract' input 1 from dtype('<m8[Y]') to dtype('<m8[ns]') with casting rule 'same_kind'
```

Secondly, in the operation the time unit changes from unix `seconds since 1970-01-01` for the original input netCDF-file to `hours since [start date]`, which in my case becomes **1959-06-21 00:00**, for the created output netCDF-file. I want the time unit to still be in `seconds since 1970-01-01`.

Does anyone have a suggestions or input to how I can solve this issue?

Thanks everyone

Comment: ... you always will have a "day-off". You must decide if you want to have missing at the first day or at the last day, or the actual leap day (1960-02-29)

Answer (score 0):

For the main part of your question, you should convert the time coordinate to an index before performing the arithmetic and use `Pandas.Timedelta`

```
ds['time'] = ds.time.to_index() - pd.Timedelta(days=3652)
```

This should work for most datetime-like indexes in Xarray.

Finally, I suggest reading [this](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/v0.14.1/io.html#time-units) section in the Xarray docs that describes how to control the encoding of time variables.

Comment: Thank you for you comment. But even this solution gives me the same output as before. The time unit changes from ```seconds since 1970-01-01``` to ```hours since 1959-06-21 00:00``` and the problem with the leap year remains.